Galois theory and outer automorphisms
The Schreier conjecture asserts that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(G) \cong \mathrm{Out}(G)$ is always a solvable group when $G$ is a finite simple group.
This result is known to be true as a corollary of the classification of finite simple groups, but no other proof is known.
(1) Is a rigorous proof of Galois theory dependent on automorphisms which are not inner?
(2) Is the classification of simple groups dependent on Galois theory?

What? No, Galois theory has nothing to do with this result, and CFSG has nothing in particular to do with Galois theory.

What does "proof of Galois theory" mean: the proof of the Galois correspondence or something more? Galois theory is about field automorphisms, not automorphisms of groups, so the motivation behind your question is unclear since I don't know what it means to say a field automorphism is inner.
I've never heard about general Galois theory being needed in the classification of finite simple groups. And while it is believed that all finite groups arise as Galois groups over $\mathbf Q$, it is still not yet known that all finite simple groups are Galois groups over $\mathbf Q$.  The answers to your questions are probably (1) this doesn't make sense and (2) no.

I looked at JS Milne just now and there is a section on automorphism groups of fields. So I would have thought that an inner automorphism of fields makes sense, and this is normal.

I had read that the automated proof of CFSG used Galois theory.

In a division ring $D$ there are ring automorphisms $x \mapsto yxy^{-1}$ where $y \not= 0$, and you may call these inner automorphisms, but since fields are commutative such automorphisms on fields are always the identity and thus are uninteresting. Did you have in mind some other notion of inner automorphism on a  field?

Where did you read that CFSG has been automated and that this uses Galois theory?
